# Use of TsN3, toluene at high temperature

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, pericyclic

My reasoning:
My understanding is in first step the alcohol’s O- does an Sn2 attack on the OTs containing carbon. In the second step I am confused where does the reaction happen in the triple bond or at the O-C-O Carbon?
[image]

Comment: You are correct about step 1. The azide will do 3+2 cycloaddtion with the alkyne to give a triazole, see here: https://www.organic-chemistry.org/synthesis/heterocycles/1,2,3-triazoles.shtm

Comment: There maybe a regiochemical issue in the 3+2 cycloaddition.